# undefined reference to method generated as lib .a with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Can you explain me why my function `AllToAll` is undefined in my example? I use CMake to generate a libNeuralNetwork.a which is called by the exemple.

*LayerFactory.hpp*

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "LayerModel.hpp"
#include "Layer.hpp"

namespace nn
{
    extern internal::LayerModel AllToAll(int numberOfNeurons, activationFunction activation = sigmoid);
}
```

*LayerFactory.cpp*

```cpp
#include "LayerFactory.hpp"
#include "AllToAll.hpp"

using namespace nn;
using namespace internal;

LayerModel AllToAll(int numberOfNeurons, activationFunction activation)
{
    LayerModel model
    {
        allToAll,
        activation,
        numberOfNeurons
    };
    return model;
}
```

*NeuralNetwork.hpp*

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "layer/LayerModel.hpp"
#include "layer/LayerFactory.hpp"

namespace nn
{
    class NeuralNetwork
    {
    public:
        NeuralNetwork(int numberOfInputs, std::vector<internal::LayerModel> models);
        //...
    };
}
```

*Example.cpp*

```cpp
#include "../src/neural_network/NeuralNetwork.hpp"

using namespace nn;

int example1()
{
    NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork(3, {AllToAll(5), AllToAll(2)});
}
```

error message:

```
CMakeFiles/UnitTests.out.dir/ExamplesTest.cpp.o: In function `example1()':
ExamplesTest.cpp:(.text+0x8b3): undefined reference to `nn::AllToAll(int, nn::activationFunction)'
```

Comment: `LayerModel AllToAll(int numberOfNeurons, activationFunction activation)` below a `using namespace nn;` doesn't automagically plant that function in that namespace. You have to qualify it at decl *and* def time (if they're separate). Surround that function with `namespace nn { .. code here }` or qualify it with `LayerModel nn::AllToAll(int numberOfNeurons, activationFunction activation)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `AllToAll` in the top-level namespace and defined it in the `nn` namespace.

The following will not declare the function in the namespace:

```cpp
using namespace foo;

extern void Bar();
```

You need:

```cpp
namespace foo {
  extern void Bar();
}
```